# Dart - How to define an interface like in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, dart

I come from Typescript, and in TypeScript, I could define an interface of an object like so:

```
export interface Locale {
  login: {
    title: string;
    actions: {
      submit: string;
      forgot: string;
    }
  }
}
```

I understand that Dart has removed interfaces, and instead, all classes have [implicit interfaces](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#implicit-interfaces)

So I tried to implement the interface I mentioned above by writing:

```
class BaseLoginActionsLocale {
  final String submit;
  final String forgot;

  BaseLoginActionsLocale({this.submit, this.forgot});
}

class BaseLoginLocale {
  final String title;
  final BaseLoginActionsLocale actions;

  BaseLoginLocale({this.title, this.actions});
}

class BaseLocale {
  final BaseLoginLocale login;

  BaseLocale({this.login});
}

...

final BaseLocale enLocale = BaseLocale(
  login: BaseLoginLocale(
    title: 'Login',
    actions: BaseLoginActionsLocale(
      submit: 'Login',
      forgot: 'Forgot Password?'
    )
  )
);
```

But I feel like it's way too much boilerplate.

So my question is, is there a better way of implementing an int

Comment: welcome to dart \o/ ...sry

Comment: the only thign I know of to make it shorter is passing the BaseLocale constructor the values of the BaseLoginLocale and BaseLoginActionsLocale as well and passing them through

Comment: @jonathanHeindl Could you post it as an answer? I'm not sure how the syntax should be

Answer (score 0):

To pass the BaseLocale all of your values you could implement it as follows:

```
class BaseLoginActionsLocale {
  final String submit;
  final String forgot;

  BaseLoginActionsLocale(this.submit, this.forgot);
}

class BaseLoginLocale {
  final String title;
  final BaseLoginActionsLocale actions;

  BaseLoginLocale(this.title, submit, forgot) : actions = new BaseLoginActionsLocale(submit, forgot);
}

class BaseLocale {
  final BaseLoginLocale login;

  BaseLocale(title, submit, forgot) : login = new BaseLoginLocale(title, submit, forgot);  
}

final BaseLocale enLocale = BaseLocale('Login', 'Login', 'Forgot Password?');
```

Note that this approach makes it the responsibility of `BaseLocale` to know the properties of its dependencies (and by extension the implementation) and may be considered as an anti-pattern by some...